# Button Requiring Two Clicks To Invoke Action

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I have a table component that displays a list of employees. I have a button with the text "Hide Table" that when clicked, I want the table to hide and the text of the button to change to "Show Table". Well, I can do it, but I have two problems:

1)The initial click on the "Hide Table" button, requires two clicks to kick off the action. But works on the first click on subsequent clicks.

2)After the initial click, my material button seems to stop being a material button. The material flat button does not appear again on hover.

https://employee-table-app.herokuapp.com

employee.table.component.html

```
<div id="matTableDiv">
  <mat-table [dataSource] = "dataSource" matSort>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="photo">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Profile</mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let employee"><img width = "50" height = "50" src = "../assets/images/{{employee.username}}.jpg" >
      </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Employee Name</mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let employee">{{employee.name}}</mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Job Title</mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let employee">{{employee.position}}</mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns" color="primary"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns:displayedColumns"></mat-row>
  </mat-table>
  <button (click)="toggle();" id="table-button" mat-button color="primary">Hide Table</button>
</div>
```

employee-table.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {MatSort, MatSortable, MatTableDataSource} from '@angular/material';
import {EmployeeService} from '../employee.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-employee-table',
  templateUrl: './employee-table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./employee-table.component.css']
})
export class EmployeeTableComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
  dataSource;
  displayedColumns = ['photo', 'name', 'position'];

  constructor() {}
  ngOnInit() {   
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource([
            {
              "id": 1,
              "name": "Leanne Grahamz",
              "username": "Bret",
              "position": "Software Developer"
            },
            {
              "id": 2,
              "name": "Ervin Howell",
              "username": "Antonette",
              "position": "Graphic Designer"
            },
            {
              "id": 3,
              "name": "Clementine Bauch",
              "username": "Samantha",
              "position": "Front End Developer"
            },
            {
              "id": 4,
              "name": "Patricia Lebsack",
              "username": "Karianne",
              "position": "Full Stack Developer"
            },
            {
              "id": 5,
              "name": "Chelsey Dietrich",
              "username": "Kamren",
              "position": "Database Administrator" 
            }
    ]); //End data object
  }//End ng onInit

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }

  toggle() {
    console.log("The hide table button was clicked.");

    var button = document.querySelector('#table-button');

    var table  = document.querySelector('.mat-table');

          if (table.style.display == "block") {
              table.style.display = "none";
              button.innerHTML = "Show Table";
          } else {
              table.style.display = "block";
              button.innerHTML = "Hide Table";
          }
  }
}//End class EmployeeTableComponent
```

Comment: Can you please post the CSS of the button and the table too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first click the table display property is not "block" (it is "table", the [default display value](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_default_values.asp) for table elements) and so it goes to the `else` block. Try to invert your logic to check if table is visible or not with:

```
if (table.style.display != "none") {
  table.style.display = "none";
  button.innerHTML = "Show Table";
} else {
  table.style.display = "table";
  button.innerHTML = "Hide Table";
}
```

Comment: That was it.  Thank you I appreciate it. CMazz